# Is There A Way to Either Return 2 values for the property floatingActionButton or to call a setState Whenever a variable Changes?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter,

So I'm working on a Flutter app & I Have My Functions & Widget File named:  **'Function'**  Separated from my **Main** but I'm trying to *set state* in **'Main'** from **'Function'**

I have tried to set a global variable inside a MyText class Widget inside **'Function'** and import **'Main'**==> **Function** & Vice Versa at the same time, but I can't seem to manipulate the **GlobalKey** variable which would trigger `setState` again

*(Class & MyText class Has since been Scrapped)*

I also tried to set the function from my other file to the button like so

`floatingActionButton: functions.random()`

And somehow was able to set state (Sorry I Forgot How), but it kept running without being pressed

**'Main.dart'** Sample Code

```
String display = "";

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var currentScreen = display;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AutoSizeText(
              currentScreen,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: functions.menu(),
    );
  } //Build
}// _MyHomePageState
```

**'Function.dart'** Sample Code

```
SpeedDial menu(){
  return SpeedDial(
      SpeedDialChild(
           child: Icon(Icons.autorenew),
           backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
           label: 'New Activity',
           labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
           onTap: () => random(),
       ),
)

random(){
...

return someString;
}
```

**Intended Result**

When Child 'New Activity' is clicked, setState is called with the variable **currentScreen's** state being set to the result from the function **'random()'**

Thank You In Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this can finish your problem, but the approach will be a little different from your approach because I'm not really familiar with the globalsetkey works...

so from my perspective I'm using the bloc pattern so hope this can give you some inspiration how to resolve this problems

in **classBLoc.dart**

```
BehaviorSubject<bool> _dialClicked = BehaviorSubject<bool>();

Observable<bool> get dialClicked => _dialClicked.stream;

Function(bool) get dialClickedListener => _dialClicked.sink.add;
```

in **main.dart**
section *floatingActionButton*,

```
floatingActionButton: functions.menu(currentScreen),
```

in **Function.dart**

```
Widget menu(){
final bloc = Provider.of<classBLoc>();
  return StreamBuilder(stream: bloc.dialClicked, initialData: false,builder: (context, snapshot){
return SpeedDial(
      SpeedDialChild(
           child: Icon(Icons.autorenew),
           backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
           label: 'New Activity',
           labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
           onTap: () => snapshot.data ? currentScreen : random(), // this used for checking data if have already been clicked or not
       );
}),
);
```

Hope this can you some inspiration how it's worked //sorry if there is wrong bracketed

Comment: Thank you! I Haven't tried it yet but those are 2 new concepts to me that I think were what I was looking for, Will post update!

Comment: Do I have to add a dependency to the pubspec.yaml? or import anything?

Comment: if you are using rxdart/Provider, you need to put some libs in pubspec

Comment: Update
I Was able to get it using FutureBuilder , Thank you!